# ℃ from mysql database cannot display on website

Tags: html, mysql, unicode

I have a Mysql database having data below:

Thermometer -10℃ - 110℃

I copied that degree symbol from other website.

I did declare on my html like some example here:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

But it just wont show up when I call this data using php to my website, it only display

```
Thermometer -10?C - 110?C
```

What else do I need to do??

Comment: Try setting a different font in CSS

Comment: Declaring that you use UTF-8 in the HTML source is possibly the most irrelevant bit. You need to ensure you're actually using UTF-8 everywhere (text editor, database table, database connection...). Also, `℃` is encoded as `E2 84 83` in UTF-8. Display the raw bytes and verify at which point it gets broken.

Comment: @Adder I don't think that's now how browsers normally work. If a glyph is unavailable in a given font you get a replacement character automatically.

Comment: Álvaro González I use utf8_general_ci in the table.

Comment: what do u mean 'Display the raw bytes and verify '? How to do it?

Comment: My editor default encode in utf-8 too..

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález My reasoning is that `℃` is actually a single character. If it shows up as `?C` then the unicode should be correct and the bug should be elsewhere

Comment: It was display correctly in my mysql table. But when I CRT V it in here with after 4 space, it become like that, I think the editor in stack overflow has its own way of encoding too...

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález it did show up up as ?C. So where else can be faulty??

Comment: I mean stuff like [HEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_hex), [bin2hex()](http://php.net/bin2hex), [hexadecimal editors](http://hexed.it), etc.

Comment: Fonts and CSS are unlikely to have any impact here.

Comment: `COLLATION utf8_general_ci`  implies `CHARACTER SET utf8` which should have both E28483 and C2B0.

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm hearing that the *single* Unicode character `℃` (hex `E28483`) is turning into the *two* Unicode characters `°C` (hex `C2B0 43`).  Let's verify this.  If encoded as latin1, the latter hex will be `B0 43`.

If the character(s) are in the database, then do

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...
```

If they are in PHP, then do

```
echo bin2hex($str);
```

Then report back which hex you get.

[*This*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) discusses why the *two* character version could turn into `?C`.  It suggests:

- The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8/utf8mb4.  In particular, hex `B0` is the latin1 encoding for `°`.
- The column in the database is not CHARACTER SET utf8 (or utf8mb4). Fix this. (Use SHOW CREATE TABLE.)
- Also, check that the connection during reading is UTF-8.

Meanwhile, there is nothing (that I know of) in either MySQL or PHP that would turn the one-char encoding into the two-char version.  Is there any other process involved?

In the Unicode specification, there is a "Decomposition" of the 1-char version into the 2-char version, but I don't know what product would make use of such.  Another example: `ǈ` vs `Lj`

**Who is converting?**

If MySQL were converting from utf8 to latin1, I would expect

```
CONVERT(CONVERT(BINARY('℃') USING utf8) USING latin1)
```

to return the two-char version.  But, no, it returns `'?'`.  I have to assume some other process that the data is going through is being kind enough to convert the 1-char thing into 2-chars, perhaps then converting to latin1 (which is almost identical to cp1252 and ISO-8859-1 and ISO-8859-15)

Comment: I run HEX(col) it does return (C2B0 43) for °C.

Comment: When I run -sql to mysql: show variables like "collation_%", it return that collation_connection is utf8mb4_bin, collation_database is utf8_unicode_ci, and collation_server is ** latin1_swedish_c**. Can this **collation_server latin1_swedish_c** be the problem??

Comment: @Newbee123 - Look for `"char%"` instead of `"collation%"`.  The hex indicates that the conversion happened _before_ `INSERTing` into the database.  What action happened then?

Comment: sql to mysql: show variables like "character%", it return:     Variable_name: Value
character_set_client: utf8mb4,
character_set_connection: utf8mb4,
character_set_database: latin1,
character_set_filesystem: binary,
character_set_results: utf8mb4,
character_set_server: latin1,
character_set_system: utf8,
character_sets_dir: /usr/share/mysql/charsets

Comment: can it be **character_set_server: latin1 that cause the problem??

Comment: @Newbee123 - latin1 has the two characters but not the single character.  MySQL will do 1:1 conversions, but not the conversion in question.  What other process is involved?  (I added to my Answer.)

Comment: @Newbee123 - and...  The `character_set_client/connection/results = utf8mb4` declare that the _client's_ bytes are encoded as `UTF-8`.  I am pretty sure that if you have the 1-char `℃` in UTF-8 in the client, and store it into a column that is `CHARACTER SET latin1`, it will be turned into `?`.  (That is, I still don't have the full answer.)